# Post preview link shows post without content

Tags: wordpress

When I click post preview link "Preview in new tab" on the post  editing site in Wordpress admin I get link like this

```
   xyz.org/lorem-ipsum-post-title/?preview_id=1527&preview_nonce=45ec83b2f1&preview=true
```

but it shows page without content. But if I remove one of this variables:

```
xyz.org/lorem-ipsum-post-title/?preview_id=1527&preview_nonce=45ec83b2f1
xyz.org/lorem-ipsum-post-title/?preview_nonce=45ec83b2f1&preview=true
```

the page is displayed properly.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the permalink of your wordpress website by following [this tutorial](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/reset-permalinks-wordpress/)

If you use Cloudflare, try to purge the cache of your website by going to your Cloudflare Dashboard>Purge Cache>Purge Everything>Ok.